# Weird reults in training AlexNet

Tags: pytorch, multiclass-classification

I’m trying to train a dataset with AlexNet model. The task is multiclass classification (15 classes). I am wondering why I am getting very low accuracy.
I tried different learning rate but has not been improved.

Here is the snippet for the training.

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9)  
#optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-2)  # 1e-3, 1e-8

def train_valid_model():

  num_epochs=5

since = time.time()
out_loss = open("history_loss_AlexNet_exp1.txt", "w")
out_acc = open("history_acc_AlexNet_exp1.txt", "w")

losses=[]
ACCes =[]
#losses = {}

for epoch in range(num_epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
    print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1))
    print('-' * 50)        

    if epoch % 10 == 9:
       torch.save({
        'epoch': epoch + 1,
        'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(),
        'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
         'loss': loss
        }, 'AlexNet_exp1_epoch{}.pth'.format(epoch+1))

    for phase in ['train', 'valid', 'test']:
        if phase == 'train':

            model.train()  
        else:
            model.eval()   

        train_loss = 0.0
        total_train = 0
        correct_train = 0

        for t_image, target, image_path in dataLoaders[phase]:
            #print(t_image.size())
            #print(target)

            t_image = t_image.to(device)
            target = target.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                outputs = model(t_image) 
                outputs = F.softmax(outputs, dim=1)


                loss = criterion(outputs,target)         
                if phase == 'train':
                    loss.backward() 
                    optimizer.step()                           

            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            train_loss += loss.item()* t_image.size(0)
            correct_train += (predicted == target).sum().item()

        epoch_loss = train_loss / len(dataLoaders[phase].dataset)
        #losses[phase] = epoch_loss
        losses.append(epoch_loss)

        epoch_acc = 100 * correct_train / len(dataLoaders[phase].dataset) 
        ACCes.append(epoch_acc)

        print('{} Loss: {:.4f} {} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(phase, epoch_loss, phase, epoch_acc))
```

This is the output for two epochs

### Epoch 0/4

train Loss: 2.7026 train Acc: 17.2509
valid Loss: 2.6936 valid Acc: 28.7632
test Loss: 2.6936 test Acc: 28.7632

### Epoch 1/4

train Loss: 2.6425 train Acc: 17.8019
valid Loss: 2.6357 valid Acc: 28.7632
test Loss: 2.6355 test Acc: 28.7632

Comment: Have you tried Adam?

Comment: @prosti Yes, I did. It didn't help

Comment: How you transit from 1000 classes of AlexNet to 15 classes or yours, do you have data normalization step included? What are your targets/labels.

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic tip, it may help you started,

```
import torchvision.models as models
alexnet = models.alexnet(pretrained=True)
```

When using alexnet you may start with the pretrained model, I haven't saw that in your code.
If you need to have just 15 classes, make sure you remove the fully connected layer at the very end, and add your new fc layer with 15 outputs,

Your alexnet looks like this:

```
AlexNet(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(11, 11), stride=(4, 4), padding=(2, 2))
    (1): ReLU(inplace)
    (2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (3): Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2))
    (4): ReLU(inplace)
    (5): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (6): Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (7): ReLU(inplace)
    (8): Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (9): ReLU(inplace)
    (10): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace)
    (12): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(6, 6))
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Dropout(p=0.5)
    (1): Linear(in_features=9216, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (2): ReLU(inplace)
    (3): Dropout(p=0.5)
    (4): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (5): ReLU(inplace)
    (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
  )
)
```

So you are in a need removing just the classifier (6) layer.
I think [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-extract-features-of-an-image-from-a-trained-model/119/2) answered how to remove the fc6.

For multi-label classification, the last layer in the model should use a sigmoid function for label prediction, and the training process should use binary_crossentropy function or `nn.BCELoss`.

Comment: yes, I did all these correctly. This line (1): Linear(in_features=9216, out_features=4096, bias=True) for me is  nn.Linear(256 * 6 * 6, 4096), which is correct. I did normalization as well, but has not been improved. Can you spot any mistake in my snippet?

Comment: What F Massa [did](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-extract-features-of-an-image-from-a-trained-model/119/3?u=blackbirdbarber), removed the last layer and next is to set the 15 outputs. Sorry for checking...

Comment: thank you. If we have nn.NLLLoss() should I keep the F.softmax(outputs, dim=1)?

Comment: for multi-label classification `nn.BCELoss` should be your choice ;)